# When and why can the spin connection term of the Dirac Operator be omitted?

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, gauge-theory, dirac-equation

The Dirac Operator $D$ is defined by
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
D=i\gamma^a\nabla_a=i\gamma^a\nabla_{e_a}=i\underbrace{\gamma^a{e_a}^\mu}_{=\gamma^\mu}\nabla_{\partial_\mu}=i\gamma^\mu\nabla_\mu=i\gamma^\mu(\partial_\mu+\omega_\mu+A_\mu)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\omega_a=-\frac{1}{4}\omega_{abc}\gamma^{bc}\psi={e_a}^\mu\omega_\mu.
\end{equation}
However, in his derivation of the Atiyah Singer Index theorem$^1$, Fujikawa (chapter $5.5$ of [Path Integrals and Quantum Anomalies](https://doi.org/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780198529132.001.0001)) assumes
\begin{equation}
D=i\gamma^\mu\nabla_\mu=i\gamma^\mu(\partial_\mu+A_\mu).
\end{equation}
One might think that Fujikawa's $D$ is simply another operator, but Nakahara - who derives the same equation in section $13.2.1$ (Fujikawa's method) - says that the spin connection "plays no role" under certain assumptions:

> We compactify the space in such a
> way that the geometry (the spin connection) plays no role. For example, this
> can be achieved by compactifying $\mathbf{R}^4$ to $S^4=\mathbf{R}^4\cup\{\infty\}$, for which the Dirac
> genus $\hat{A}(TM)$ is trivial.

I know that $S^n\cong\mathbf{R}^n\cup\{\infty\}$, but I don't see why this implies that the spin connection "plays no role".

---

$^1$ By the "Atiyah Singer Index theorem" I mean the equation
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{ind}\,D_+=-\frac{1}{8\pi^2}\int_M\mathrm{tr}(F_{ij}F_{kl})\epsilon^{ijkl}\cdot\omega,
\end{equation}
where $M$ is a $4$-dimensional Riemannian manifold with euclidean signature and $\omega$ is the volume form. (I am aware of the fact that $D\colon\Gamma(M,S\otimes E)\to\Gamma(M,S\otimes E)$ is a Fredholm operator and that $(1)$ is only valid after the choice of a local gauge - here we assume that $E$ is the the associated vector bundle induced by the adjoint representation.)

Answer (score 2):

If you compacify to a torus then, in Cartesian coordinates, the spin connection vanishes and so is irrelevent. If you compactify to a sphere, as Fujikawa suggests, it is far less obvious that $\hat A(TM)$ is not needed. That it  plays no role  is because $\hat A(TM)$ is a [*genus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_of_a_multiplicative_sequence) and so cobordism invariant. This means that the curvature contribution to the index is zero when $M$ is a boundary: $M=\partial N$, and the spin connection can be extended through $N$.  This is true in the case of a sphere. I do not know a  simple proof of the cobordism property  though.

That there are no geometry-induced zero modes on a sphere *is* easy to prove with physicist's tools. You can find a discussion in the first few pages of my lecture notes [here](http://people.physics.illinois.edu/stone/lichnerowicz.pdf).

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, I know nothing about the A hat genus (and its correlation with the spin connection) and I don't understand Nakahara's definition - could you please suggest a good text to start with?

Comment: About the *genus* just about all I know is in the Wikipedia artcle I cited.  I do know that histoically the A-S theorem was proved via  the cobordism invariance. The heat equation came later, I think, due to Gilkey's work. Google Gilkey and heat equation.

Comment: I think I totally misunderstood the phrase "the spin connection plays no role/is irrelevant". We can't prove that the spin connection is equal to zero - what we really mean is that it plays no role/is irrelevant when proving the special case of the Atiyah Singer Index theorem  I mentioned in my question. And that's because the spin connection doesn't contribute to/appear in the topological index (the RHS).

Comment: To prove the ASIT, it doesn't suffice to prove $\mathrm{ind}\,D_+=-\frac{1}{8\pi^2}\int_M\mathrm{tr}(F_{ij}F_{kl})\epsilon^{ijkl}\cdot\omega$ like I did, but one needs to show that RHS is equal to the topological index and that's where the A hat genus joins the party. Considering the operator $i\gamma^\mu(\partial_\mu+A_\mu)$ is useful to prove $\mathrm{ind}\,D_+=-\frac{1}{8\pi^2}\int_M\mathrm{tr}(F_{ij}F_{kl})\epsilon^{ijkl}\cdot\omega$, but $i\gamma^\mu(\partial_\mu+A_\mu)$ is not the Dirac operator. (A confirmation would be appreciated.)

Comment: Yes. There are curvature  terms coming from $\hat A$ in in the expression for the index general spin manifolds. Even when $\hat A$ makes not contribution you will need the spin connection to makes ense of the Dirac operator.

Comment: Thank you very much, you have helped me a lot!